# High Sierra 10.13.4 Transparency Not working

Tags: high-sierra, software-update

With the recent update to 10.13.4 I now have issues with applications, notifications area and any other area that is showing images or text with a transparency.

I would show you a screenshot but when you do take a screenshot it actually renders correctly. Therefore I need to describe it... it is like a highlight of the general colour as though you were highlighting the image or text in word. It is not a strong highlight but it is very annoying nevertheless. Actually will take a photo on my phone:
[image]

What it should look like:
[image]

I have a Mac Pro with a Nvidia Geforce 680 in it so I believe that it might be something related to the new eGPU support.

Any ideas?

Comment: To clarify, are you the developer of the app in the screenshot, or a user of the app? If you're using the app and having issues after 10.13.4, I would make sure there are no updates available from the developer, or otherwise contact them for assistance.

Comment: I am the user of the app but this is just one example it also happens in the Apple notification area and many many other applications. it is not specific to this application.

Comment: Thank you. Have you by chance enabled Reduce Transparency in the Accessibility settings? You can check by going to System Preferences–>Display–>Reduce transparency

Comment: Hi @Jake3231 I am guessing that you actually mean System Preferences -> Accessibility -> Display -> Reduce Transparency. Yes I have used this and it sort of works in some applications but not across the board. I would prefer to see it as a FIX rather than a workaround. This reduce transparency also only works in some applications it does NOT work for the application shown above for example.